# I am trying to write a query but it is not working with lag function

Tags: hive, hiveql

I need to do partition on aa bb cc columns order by date and need results like if the difference is more than 60 days in consecutive rows. I tried with datediff(date,lag()) but not getting expected results.

[image: see the expected results column]

Comment: Could you show the query that you have tried?

Comment: date should be in sortable format for order by: yyyy-MM-dd

Answer (score 0):

Assuming date is a datetime type column, you can use below code -
`CASE when datediff(date,lag(Date, 1, 0) over (order by Date) ) >60 then 1 else 0 END diff_gt_60`